# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\vufo\vuforiaApi.php on line 208

Tags: php, vuforia

I want to create CRUD data json in table. I want to send variable to client.php and create table in another php file, but in client PHP I want to test echo the variable. this code run if me print the variable from function

Line 208 is functions list_targets($data)

This vuforiaapi.php:

```php
class VuforiaCloud
{
    # Cloud server secret and access codes
    private $secret;

    private $access;

    # Request object to be used across methods
    private $request;

    public $result;

    # Constants
    const URL = "https://vws.vuforia.com";

    public function __construct($access, $secret)
    {
        $this->secret = $secret;
        $this->access = $access;
        $this->result = null;
    }

    public function list_targets($data)
    {
        $requestPath = "/targets";
        $this->init_get_request();
        $this->request->setURL(VuforiaCloud::URL . $requestPath);
        $this->build_headers_request();
        try {
            $this->result = $this->request->send();
            if (200 == $this->result->getStatus()) {
                $json = json_decode($this->result->getBody());
                $data = $this->$json->results;
            }
        } catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
            echo '<h2>Fatal error! HTTP_Request2_Exception</h2>';
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

This class client:

```php
<?php 
require_once 'vuforiaApi.php';
$access = "mycodeacces";
$secret = "mycodeacces";
$api = new VuforiaCloud($access, $secret);

$array = $api->list_targets($data);
?>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace to your question? The error will occur inside your `list_targets($data)` method but the exact line would be necessary to further help.

Comment: @SaschaM78 how to get stacktrace in php code?

Comment: I would recommend to move your `try {` to the beginning of your function and replace `catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception_2_exception $e)` with a generic `catch (Exception $e)` along with error display inside the catch block (`print $e->getMessage() . ' at line '.$e->getLine()`).

Comment: @SaschaM78 i change the try and catch. but i get some error **Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\vufo\client.php on line 8** and **Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\vufo\vuforiaApi.php on line 210**

Comment: What's your question about this code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase solved

Answer (score 0):

You should not echo the result. Use the `return` statement to return the result of a method / function instead.

```php
$this->result = $this->request->send();
$status = $this->result->getStatus();
if ($status == 200) {
    $json = json_decode($this->result->getBody());

    return $json;
}

throw new RuntimeException('Request failed with status code: ' . $status);
```

Comment: if me use return. php code give me error message      Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\vufo\vuforiaApi.php on line 208

Comment: Try to replace `$data = $this->$json->results;` with `return $json`.

Comment: if me replace $data and return $json. script dont show anything. i echo variable $json after return this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code and one will be throwing a "Recoverable Fatal Error". Let's start with the call of the method:

1. You are passing in `$data` as a parameter but it hasn't been created (at least in the section of code posted). This would raise an E_NOTICE.
2. You are assigning a variable to a void method as no data is being returned by `list_targets($data)`. If you later-on access it, it might give you unexpected results.
3. Possibility of mixing by-reference/by-variable: you pass in variable `$data` (as mentioned above not set before) and assign values to it using `$data = $this->$json->results;`. If no ampersand is preceding a parameter in a function definition (e.g. `function returnByRef(&$varName)`) the parameter cannot be changed within the function scope and will be the same as was passed in into the function.
4. Finally this line contains the error which is causing the exception:

```
  $json = json_decode($this->result->getBody());
  $data = $this->$json->results;
```

- You are decoding the result of the `result->getBody()` and assign it to `$json`. This will now be an object, array or variable, depending on the returned data.
- in the next line you try to access the class instance scope's `$this` and try to access its property `$json`. Not only this, you are chaining a method call to it. This property hasn't been set (and I would strongly advise against "variable variables" like `$this->$property`) so you are now calling a method on a non-object. The proper variable would have been the local variable `$json`.

**Changed code**

In fact you would only have to return the decoded JSON like so:

```
if (200 == $this->result->getStatus()) {
  return json_decode($this->result->getBody());
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

To be honest - and comments would be highly appreciated - I still wonder why this causes a *"could not be converted to string"* error. Only idea would be that the raised exception is somehow trying to call `__toString()` on a non-object.

Comment: idont understand what do yo mean about number one. can you give me a sample code for number one. and if me return `json_decode($this->result->getbody()` and then i echo script doesnt't show anything

Comment: @Herlambang I mean in the code you posted there is no `$data= array();` before you call `$api->list_targets($data)`. What is the content of `print_r($this->result->getbody());` before you JSON-decode it?

Comment: `print_r($this->result->getbody());` is a json {"result_code":"Success","transaction_id":"21a4de3b14684a0881b386a2d1e8c044","results":["f248175c2a6f4bcf9d9df6fe3e367ab5","6c104d59194e40e5826b692c0d6198f1","9e69ab58ad6d42b68c2da25e80c0e36c"]}

Comment: @Herlambang could you edit your question and add an update with your current code? So what might happen is that `$this->result->getStatus()` does not return 200 so the script returns `FALSE` which would then be the content of your `$array` variable. The JSON is valid so if `return json_decode($this->result->getBody());` is executed, the decoded JSON would be stored in the array instead.

Comment: i update my code to mvc in this link question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834955/how-to-passing-data-array-json-mvc-with-php can you help me with that question